# Populating an attribute field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I want to add another field to an attribute table, a number field. This number field will show in my opinion the experience visiting the ski resort, from 1 (the worst) to 10 (the best). Those that I have not visited will get 0 by default when I add the field, then I want to populate the ones I have visited with a value from 1 to 10. How do I go about this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this in arcpy?  I've posted a non-arcpy answer below, however if you want an arcpy solution you need to [edit] your question to include what code you've tried and outline what's not working for you and any error's you get.

Comment: @Topher_Fabbri: Are you using ArcMap?

Comment: @Midavalo Valid assumption, but considering they are asking how to perform GIS 101 procedures yet tag it "python" & "arcpy", I'm not confident Topher even knows what "arcpy" really means. So, I'm trying to confirm the assumption.

Comment: @alexGIS good call

Comment: I have to create it in python for a final project and its one of the last steps i wanted to add in... @alexGIS seems like a pretty help full guy.

Comment: @TopherFabbri please include the python code you're stuck with and any errors you get.

Comment: As an aside, using 0 to mean null, is very bad practice. Imagine taking the average rating and forgetting to exclude the zeros, something that could easily happen in a big system with many users.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need `arcpy` for this.

In Arcmap open the Attribute table

[image]

click on the context menu and select Add Field

[image]

Type in the name of your new field and make sure the field type is set to "Short Integer" and add a Default Vaule of `0` and click OK.  This will add the new field to your attribute table.

[image]

Note that this Default Value will not automatically apply to any existing features, so you will need to populate these with a `0`.

From the Editor toolbar select Start Editing

[image]

Then in your attribute table right-click the new field column header and select Field Calculator

[image]

In the Calculate Field dialog type `0` into the expression input box and click OK

[image]

Now all your existing features have a value of `0`

[image]

You can now edit any of your existing features to add your ratings 1-10, either by typing the values into the attribute table against each feature

[image]

or by selecting a feature in the map display and opening the Attributes editor and typing in your value

[image]

Remember to Stop Editing and save.

[image]

Comment: Now that is an excellent answer!